# Gerar número aleatório entre dois números com Math.random()

Tags: java, random

Preciso gerar um numero aleatório entre *1000* e *9999*, encontrei a seguinte fórmula:

```
(int) (min + Math.random() * (max+1))
```

Código:

```
int numeroAleatorio = (int) (1000 + Math.Random() * 10000);
System.out.println("Thread A: " + numeroAleatorio);
```

Mas gerou um número maior que *9999*, como pode ser visto na imagem abaixo.

[image: Código]

Comment: Você pode colocar seu código como texto mesmo? Fica ruim para as pessoas ajudarem desta forma. Eu mesmo não tive tanta vontade de responder poque não pude usar o código para testar a solução que eu daria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fórmula correta seria:

```
((int)(min + Math.random() * (max - min + 1))
```

Ou se preferir:

```
Random random = new Random();
return random.nextInt((maximo - minimo) + 1) + minimo;
```

Seu código poderia ser testado assim:

```
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) System.out.println((int)(1000 + Math.random() * (10000 - 1000 + 1)));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/z37eIn). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dflybdhb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/RandomRange4.java).

Se a intenção for usar um gerador de randômicos concorrentes de forma isolada, é só trocar pelo [`ThreadLocalRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt-int-int-).

Answer (score 4):

O método [`Math#random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) retorna um double igual ou superior à *0.0* e menor que *1.0*.

```
int numeroAleatorio = (int) (1000 + Math.Random() * 10000);
```

Um dos problemas do código é que não é indicado o valor mínimo, ao invés disso é multiplicado o valor máximo pelo valor de `Math.Random`, que pode ser por exemplo: *0.02* ou *0.98*, depois soma-se o valor mínimo.

O correto seria subtrair o valor máximo e mínimo e somar *1* (se você quiser que o valor máximo possa ser retornado aleatoriamente), então multiplicar pelo valor de `Math.random`, finalmente, basta somar o valor mínimo para indicar o começo do intervalo.

```
public static int numeroAleatorio(int a, int b) {
    final int min = Math.min(a, b);
    final int max = Math.max(a, b);

    return min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
}
```

<sub>**Nota**: O *casting* para `int` é necessário para truncar o resultado (devido ao `Math.random` retornar um `double`).</sub>

Se preferir usar [`Random#nextInt-int`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) ao invés de `Math#random`:

```
public static int numeroAleatorio2(int a, int b) {
    final int min = Math.min(a, b);
    final int max = Math.max(a, b);

    Random r = new Random();
    return min + r.nextInt((max - min) + 1);
}
```

Para usar, basta fazer assim:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println(numeroAleatorio(1000, 9999));
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/lCyNQ5)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Da uma olhada em:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
```